# Как заменить точку в слове?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Как во всем тексте заменить символ точки, который стоит только внутри самого слова?

Например : **Продам автомобиль б.у недорого.** заменить на **Продам автомобиль б/у недорого.**

Answer (score 5):

Если текст в кодировке UTF-8, то при соседстве с буквами можно сделать так

```
$text = preg_replace('%(?<=\p{L})\.(?=\p{L})%u', '/', $text);
```

а для букв и цифр так

```
$text = preg_replace('%(?<=[\p{L}\p{N}])\.(?=[\p{L}\p{N}])%u', '/', $text);
```

В обоих случаях используется [позитивный просмотр](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%E3%F3%EB%FF%F0%ED%FB%E5_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%FF#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4) назад и вперед.

Тест https://regex101.com/r/H7o9el/2

Answer (score 5):

Просто вот так

```
$string = str_replace('б.у', 'б/у', $string);
```